# Erro ao carregar XML em XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

Estou consumindo um WebService com o seguinte código

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(link);

byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = bytesToWrite.Length;
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", link);

Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
newStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Se eu salvar a resposta em um arquivo consigo ler normalmente, 
`var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp\Arquivo.xml");`

Se eu tentar carregar direto

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Aparece o seguinte erro :

> System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2146232000
>     LineNumber=0
>     LinePosition=0
>     Message=Elemento raiz inexistente.
>     Source=System.Xml
>     SourceUri=""
>    StackTrace:
>          em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>          em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>          em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>          em System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
>          em System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(TextReader textReader, LoadOptions options)
>          em System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(TextReader textReader)